# Calling a method from another class that has its own variables

Tags: java, methods

So I'm trying to call my method `printDetails()` from the `Customer` class in CustomerTest class. The values of the variables are not being recorded and I end up getting null for the name and an error for the array when I run it. I'm just not sure on how to get the values for the variables to be recorded and printed out.

```java
public class Customer {   
    public String name;
    public int[] itemCost;    
    public void printDetails(){
        System.out.print("Great, here is your customer's purchase details: \n");
        System.out.print("Name:"+name);
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCost.length; i ++){
            System.out.print("Item Cost #" + (i+1) + " : ");
            System.out.print(itemCost[i] + "\n");       
            }
        int sum = IntStream.of(itemCost).sum();
        System.out.println("Total:" + sum);
    }
}

public class CustomerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Customer main = new Customer();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you want to create a customer? \n");
        String s = scan.next();
        if(s.equals("y") || s.equals("yes")){
            System.out.print("Ok, what's his/her name? \n");
            String name = scan.next();
            System.out.print("How many items is the customer buying? \n");
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            int itemCost[] = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCost.length; i ++){
                System.out.print("Enter a value for item #"+(i+1) );
                System.out.printf("%n");
                int j = scan.nextInt();                              
                itemCost[i] = j;
            }
        main.printDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually have to assign things to the variables in your instance of `Customer`, e.g. `main.name = scan.next();` instead of `String name = scan.next()`.

Answer (score 0):

You save the values from you scanner in local variables and don't add them to the variables of the Customer.

Should look like this:

```
    Customer main = new Customer();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Do you want to create a customer? \n");
    String s = scan.next();
    if(s.equals("y") || s.equals("yes")){
        System.out.print("Ok, what's his/her name? \n");
        main.name = scan.next();    //HERE
        System.out.print("How many items is the customer buying? \n");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        main.itemCost = new int[n];    //HERE
        for (int i = 0; i < main.itemCost.length; i ++){    //HERE
            System.out.print("Enter a value for item #"+(i+1) );
            System.out.printf("%n");
            int j = scan.nextInt();                              
            main.itemCost[i] = j;    //AND HERE
        }
    main.printDetails();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign value for instance of `Customer` class.

**Sample Code**

```
 public class CustomerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Customer main = new Customer();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you want to create a customer? \n");
        String s = scan.next();
        if(s.equals("y") || s.equals("yes")){
            System.out.print("Ok, what's his/her name? \n");
            String name = scan.next();
            main.name = name;             //added to assign value of name to Custommer's name.
            System.out.print("How many items is the customer buying? \n");
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            int itemCost[] = new int[n];
             main.itemCost = new int[n];   //Here also need to initialize size for array.
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCost.length; i ++){
                System.out.print("Enter a value for item #"+(i+1) );
                System.out.printf("%n");
                int j = scan.nextInt();                              
                itemCost[i] = j;
                main.itemCost[i] = j; //added to assign value of itemCost to Custommer's itemCost.
            }
        main.printDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

now you can not get null value for `name` and `itemCost`.

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Setters` **method** in your `Customer` Class, so you can set the values from `CustomerTest` to `Customer` Class variables. Like this:

**Customer Class:**

```
public class Customer {   
public String name;
public int[] itemCost;    
public void printDetails(){
    System.out.print("Great, here is your customer's purchase details: \n");
    System.out.print("Name:"+name);
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCost.length; i ++){
        System.out.print("Item Cost #" + (i+1) + " : ");
        System.out.print(itemCost[i] + "\n");       
        }
    int sum = IntStream.of(itemCost).sum();
    System.out.println("Total:" + sum);
}
/**
 * Your Setters method...
 */
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public void setItemCost(int[] itemCost){
    this.itemCost= itemCost;
}
}
```

after that, you use it in `CustomerTest` like this:

**CustomerTest Class:**

```
// In the End part of your CustomerTestClass
main.setName(name);
main.setItemCost(itemCost);
main.printDetails();
```

Comment: I ended up figuring out on my own but this is how i did it thanks!

Comment: that's great, you should have setters for a good design of your `classes`. mind if you want to check to help others with my answer. @JeremyLleva.

Answer (score 0):

You have created same variables in CustomerTest as in Customer class.

This won't work, as there is no binding between these local - CustomerTest class variables and actual Customer object properties.

You need to do the following to actually make the change reflect to all places :

```
class CustomerTest{

    public static void main(){
    ...
    ...
    Scanner sc = new Scanner();
    Customer obj = new Customer();
    obj.name = sc.next();
    ...
    ...
    //Test print function
    obj.printDetails();
    }
}
```

This will work!
Point to remember: Making same name variables across class doesn't persist the value between objects!

Answer (score 0):

you can use setter and getter to set value for customer's `name` and `itemCost`, then call `printDetails()` method, when use this approach, you have to create customer object for each one, on another hand you can pass value by parameter for   `printDetails()` like that `public void printDetails(String name, int[] itemCost) { // same logic here }` then call it using `main.printDetails(name, itemCost);`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a Customer constructor with name and itemCost as parameters, like this

```
public Customer(String name, int[] itemCost){
    this.name = name;
    this.itemCost = itemCost;
}
```

and in your test class you can buil a Customer object after the user input, like this

```
public class CustomerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Customer main; // = new Customer();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you want to create a customer? \n");
        String s = scan.next();
        if(s.equals("y") || s.equals("yes")){
            System.out.print("Ok, what's his/her name? \n");
            String name = scan.next();
            System.out.print("How many items is the customer buying? \n");
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            int itemCost[] = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCost.length; i ++){
                System.out.print("Enter a value for item #"+(i+1) );
                System.out.printf("%n");
                int j = scan.nextInt();                              
                itemCost[i] = j;
            }
        main = new Customer(name, itemCost);
        main.printDetails();
        }
    }
```